# How to remove gap on my adapter row layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a layout row that is used on adapter like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_related"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ini Judul Related" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_related"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:text="Jumat, 21 Desember 2018 04:45"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_related"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/picture"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is, there is always a gap that separates between the large enough layouts. Even though I have removed all the padding, like the left and right padding. Is there something I don't see?
In addition, the display is looked like this:
[image: row layout with big gap]
You can copy this layout code snippet and paste it to your test layout to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `ImageView`. You have set `android:layout_height="200dp"` which will enforce the view to Height to be at least `200dp` regardless of the actual size of the image. Since your Parent layout is `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` you will get above behavior.

One way to solve this is to set the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` inside `ImageView`. The drawback of this approach is, you lose control over the height of ImageView. If the actual image height is like `300dp` then the view will be huge.

Another way is to reduce the height of `ImageView`. Do it only if you want to enforce specific height to all the images.

Comment: but I have to make that wide size

Comment: @NandaZ Great :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 10dp padding at the end of imageview.
Also try using min(/max)height  and min(/max)width instead of absolute value.

And you can always scale your  image ,set scaletype to fitXY

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ImageView` like below code. This will keep the width as you required.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_related"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/picture"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
```

Comment: thanks, its simillar answer with sagat. I took his answer